# gmmap with zoom=1 not displaying

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to plot a world map using `zoom=1` in the code below and it is not displaying, but when I put any other zoom number (for example 4) it is working perfectly...

Any idea why it is not working with `zoom=1`?

```
library(ggmap)
map <- qmap('world', zoom = 1)
map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the documentation here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf

"Map zoom, an integer from 3 (continent) to 21 (building), default value 10 (city).Openstreetmaps limits a zoom of 18, and the limit on stamen maps depends
on the maptype. ’auto’ automatically determines the zoom for bounding box
specifications, and is defaulted to 10 with center/zoom specifications. **Maps of
the whole world currently not supported."**

Answer (score 0):

For a little more flexibility on zooming, check out the [leaflet](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) package. It is possible to do full-world maps with that package.