# plotting large data set on google static world map using R

Tags: r, geospatial, ggmap

I'm new to R. I have a large csv which contains 4M of Latitude Longitude values. i want to plot these lat long values on google map by using ggmap. i've tried some samples but background map is missing...only colored dots are appears on graph.

Below is the code i'm trying to use:

```
require('ggmap')
data<-read.csv(file = "full_data.csv")
map.in <- get_map(location =c(lon=0, lat=10), source = "google", zoom=1, maptype="roadmap", color = 'bw')
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 6))
pred.stat.map <- ggmap(map.in) %+% data +
  aes(x = Long,
      y = Lat, z=1) +
  stat_summary2d(fun = median,
                 binwidth = c(.05, .05),
                 alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Score",
                       colours = "red",
                       space = "Lab") +
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
  coord_map()
print(pred.stat.map)
ggsave(filename = "world_map.png",
       plot = pred.stat.map,
       scale = 1,
       width = 10, height = 5,
       dpi = 400)
```

Comment: Problem with `zoom=1`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351968/gmmap-with-zoom-1-not-displaying)

Comment: I think the problem here isn't zoom = 1. Tried this example with zoom = 'auto', and it plots over a gray background, map is not showing.